# How to apply this CSS class to a given LinkButton?

Tags: asp.net, css

```
a:link
{ 
    color: white; 
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid white; 
}

a:visited
{ 
    color: white; 
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid white; 
}

a:hover
{
    color: black; 
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid black; 
}
```

Button :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="A" runat="server" Text="A"
    OnClick="searchalpha" cssClass="a" />
```

It's not working -- do you have any solution for this?

Comment: is your CSS inbetween <style></style> elements?

Comment: It's confusing to conflate the HTML element "<a>", the css class "a", and the id "A" all within the same element.

Comment: hey this is just a link button with id A and text A if i have another linkbutton for the same style sheet how can i apply it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of a class in CSS must start with a . (dot).

So your CSS should be

```
a.myclass:link{

}
```

etc.

and in the asp:LinkButton you can set the cssClass attribute to myclass

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="A" runat="server" Text="A" OnClick="searchalpha" cssClass="myclass"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know asp so I don't know what HTML is render by such a LinkButton tag.

But here I see that you set the cssClass to "a". Which means that the associated CSS class is

```
.a{ /* your style */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.mylink
{
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover.mylink
{
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

You will find it useful...